# Git Client for OS X & Windows?

Tags: git

Does anybody know of a stable release of a GUI Git Client?

Preferrably one that can run on both Mac OS X & Windows.....

Heard about SmartGit but it's still in Beta and i'm not sure I have time for trial and error.

If not, A stable one for either OS would be suitable too.

Kind regards

**EDIT:

I have read the list of potential clients that is hosted on the wiki for GIT.....
I am simply asking for advice from people who have used GIT Clients....

Answer (score 4):

This one is a variation of TortoiseSVN for Windows only

https://tortoisegit.org/

Answer (score 1):

Before someone else says it, you could always install [CYGWIN](http://www.cygwin.com/) and run GIT natively, however I am not a fan of that!

I found this - [Msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) which appears to be a native Windows implementation of Git.

Answer (score 1):

I use [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), and although it is still a preview release, I've had good luck with it.  If you're looking for a stable release on windows you can either go with the officially supported cygwin install (it's not fun), or wait a little longer.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, I highly recommend the already mentioned [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). Once installed it is a dream to work with but make sure you also grab [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to handle the SSH keys side.

As for Mac, I recently found [Gitti](http://www.gittiapp.com/) which works extremely well for me. I find the other clients to be bloated.

Also if you using Xcode 4 or RubyMine on the Mac you'll find that they have native Git clients built-in that work quite well. If you're using Visual Studio I recommend using [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X GUI for git is [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/).

[Windows Git implementation](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)

Answer (score 0):

People have already mentioned TortoiseGit. Also, some IDEs have support for git, but it's going to depend on the type of development you're doing. I write Java code using [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), which has a pretty decent support for git. Nothing fancy, but good enough for pushing and pulling code from by bitbucket account.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, take a look at [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) and [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) for Windows.

Since you didn't specify free clients, the only 'stable' client I know for OSX is [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/).

You may also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows) for more suggestions on Windows clients.

Answer (score 0):

I second Tower (http://www.git-tower.com/). It's the best Git client for OSX by far! I use it for multiple clients and multiple hosting providers.

One thing to note is that it is advertised as SVN friendly, but I find that to be false. I don't use it for SVN, so it works out fine, but just do not purchase it with the intent of using SVN with it too.

Oh! And I find the support via Twitter (@gittower) to be better than filling out a report on their website. The second best is emailing them directly (support@git-tower.com). If all else fails, fill out the form and say a prayer!

It is a bit of money, but it is WELL worth it in my opinion. It is not yet available on Windows, but SmartGIT is the best (and only, to a certain extent) GUI that is available on OSX and Windows (and Linux, if thats your thing). And its free for personal, non-commercial use too.

Best of luck!