# Using GIT on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git Client for OS X & Windows?!?](https://superuser.com/questions/29412/git-client-for-os-x-windows)

I tried running GIT on Windows about 4 months ago and it was horrible to set up. Has the setup process become more streamlined?

Comment: Voted as such. I would suggest TortoiseGit or some manual for the set up...

Answer (score 1):

horrible?
[msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) is hardly horrible to setup and wasn't 4 months ago either

Comment: +1 to msysgit. Add GitExtensions and git becomes a breeze to use

Comment: GitExtensions lives [here](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/). Version 2.00 was actually just uploaded yesterday :)